# Why does this function include 0 in the list - lists in R

Tags: r, list

As part of a bigger function in R I am creating a list that shall always contain (1:n-1). I noticed that something with this part of my function was wrong and then saw that my list always contained 0, even though I intended it to start at 1. Why does my list contain 0?

```r
N = 10
n = 2     
while(n <= N){ 
  existingV = c(1:n-1) 
  print(existingV)
  n = n+1
}
```

my expected result was:

```r
1
12
123
1234
....
```

but it actually returns

```
01
012
0123
01234
```

...why?

Comment: You want `existingV = 1:(n-1)`. Compare `1:5-1` vs. `1:(5-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Besides the needed brackets around `(n-1)`, you should think of other ways doing that. Loops in R are very often slow, but R has a nifty feature called vectorization, which may help to speed up your code considerably.

Despite also being a (hidden) loop, the `*apply` family is worth studying. `purrr::map` family is another option.

Finally to avoid this rather common trap with `1:n - 1`, you could fall back to `seq` where you can specify start end end in a more verbose way.

Having said that your code could look like this:

```
purrr::walk(seq(2, 10, 1), ~ print(seq_len(.x - 1)))
```